# Puppet could not parse environment error

Tags: puppet

I am currently running into the following error:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at end of file on node master.domain.org
```

while trying to run the below puppet code

```
puppet apply --parser future -e '$vars={ 
  0 => '192.1.1.140', 
  1 => '192.1.1.141', 
  2 => '192.1.1.142', 
} each($vars) |$id,$gate| { notice "${id} -> ${gate}" }'
```

Strangely though I can run this without issues,

```
puppet apply --parser future -e '$vars={ 
  0 => '1.0', 
  1 => '1.1', 
  2 => '1.2', 
} each($vars) |$id,$gate| { notice "${id} -> ${gate}" }'

Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 0 -> 1.0
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 1 -> 1.1
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 2 -> 1.2
Notice: Compiled catalog for master.domain.org in environment production in 0.33 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.01 seconds
```

I assume it is something with the second(and third) dot, How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I was doing some more testing and noticed this little gem

```
puppet apply --parser future -e '$ip='1.1-1' $vars={ 
  0 => "${ip}.0", 
  1 => "${ip}.1", 
  2 => "${ip}.2", 
} each($vars) |$id,$gate| { notice "${id} -> ${gate}" }'

Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 0 -> 0.10000000000000009.0
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 1 -> 0.10000000000000009.1
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): 2 -> 0.10000000000000009.2
Notice: Compiled catalog for master.domain.org in environment production in 0.34 seconds
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
```

Looks like its doing some weird mathematical expansion/interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems in this case, you need use double quote.

```
puppet apply --parser future -e '$vars={ 
  0 => "192.1.1.140", 
  1 => "192.1.1.141", 
  2 => "192.1.1.142", 
} each($vars) |$id,$gate| { notice "${id} -> ${gate}" }'
```